# Eliminating all data over a given percentile group by other columns

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, outliers, percentile

Eliminating all data over a given percentile group by other columns 
how can I add a group by to this code 
`df[df.a < df.a.quantile(.95)]`
or 
`df[df.a < np.percentile(df.a,95)]`

Comment: You add it after the boolean indexing: `df[df.a < df.a.quantile(.95)].groupby(...)`

Comment: Thanks ! , how do i put the results into a dataframe and not DataFrameGroupBy